# CSS to indicate if "tensed"-div is past, present or future?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, time

Let me explain:

I'm developing an HTML5 based mobile app for a music festival which runs for a week and has multiple events on at any given time, and I'd like to include a feature which shows events that have passed as greyed out. So if the festival ran Monday through Sunday, and it is currently noon on Tuesday, then any events on Monday will be greyed out, and any events that finish before to noon on Tuesday will also be greyed out (and events that are currently on at noon on Tuesday will be highlighted).

The app has multiple pages and multiple ways of seeing the events, but in every case the details of an event will be contained within a div;
**I'm looking for a tidy algorithm/technique to mark a div (which has an associated datetime) as being either in the past, present, or future**

**Options I've considered**:

1. put a "tensed" class on every relevant div as well as a attribute indicating the start and end times *(something like `start="yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm"`), and when a page is loaded I use javascript to loop through all divs with class tensed and look at the start-* and end-* class and add either a 'past', 'now', or 'future' class based on that, and in CSS I just have styling setup on those 3 classes.

Pseudo jQuery code (on page load):

```
$('.tensed').each(function() { 
     $(this).removeClasses('past', 'present', 'future')
            .addClass(myGetTenseClassForThisTimeFunc($(this).attr('start')); 
}
```

*What I don't like about this approach is needing to use code to apply the classes, which will take some processing time and power, and just seems bulky and yucky and clunky*

2. have a date-time class on every relevant div for the start and end time of events: *`start-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm`* and *`end-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm`* (eg. *`start-2015-10-13-10-43`*). then, programatically, every minute I guess, I adjust the styling for all possible classes in the range.

Pseudo jQuery code:

```
setTimeout( function() {
    dt = getDateTimeAsTimestampFunc();
    dt_start = getFestivalStartTime();
    dt_end = getFestivalEndTime();
    dt_loop = dt_start;
    while(dt_loop<dt_end) {
      if (dt_loop<dt) $(dt_loop).css(*make it greyedout*);
      if (dt_loop==dt) $(dt_loop).css(*make it highlighted*);
      incrementDateTimeByOneMinute(dt_loop);
    }
}, 1000);
```

*Something like that - but a bit smarter for start and end dates.  This is less elegant than the first option.*

**I feel like there must be a more elegant way to solve this, but I've not come up with anything better than the above -- I'm most interested in a pure CSS solution**
Please include pseudo code to explain your answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First option sounds simple enough. Can exclude past ones and make sure that the `past` class is on them when they get rendered initially.

Using `data-start` and `data-end` for your attributes:

```
var minutesUpdate = 10;

function updateTimeClasses() {
    var now = new Date();

    $('.tensed').not('.past').each(function () {
        var $el = $(this),
            start = new Date($el.data('start')),
            end = new Date($el.data('end')),
            isOver = end > now,
            isCurrent = start <= now && now <= end;

        if (isOver || isCurrent) {
             $el.toggleClass('present', isCurrent).toggleClass('past', isOver);
        }  
    });

}

setInterval(updateTimeClasses, minutesUpdate * 60 *1000);
```

I don't really see a need for a future class as that would be your default styling

Another suggestion would be to use a `timeUntil` function to update display for each one

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's a pure CSS solution since you would need to dynamically update the current one in some way. If you could somehow do that you could use the `~` selector and do something like:

```
.current {
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Future Events */
.current ~ li {
  color: red;
}
```

with:

```
<ol class="events">
  <li class="event"></li>
  <li class="event"></li>
  <li class="event current"></li>
  <li class="event"></li>
  <li class="event"></li>
  <li class="event"></li>
  <li class="event"></li>
</ol>
```

Though, this really isn't a lot to manage with Javascript.

You can do something like:

```
(function updateEventClasses () {
  var now = new Date();

  $events.each(function () {
    var $event = $(this);

    var start = $event.data('start');
    var end = $event.data('end');

    $event
      .toggleClass('event--past', start < now && end < now)
      .toggleClass('event--present', start > now && end < now)
      .toggleClass('event--future', start > now && end > now)

  });

  setTimeout(updateEventClasses, 60000);
}());
```

Where the `data-start` and `data-end` attributes would be `Date` objects for the time (or you could do like `data-start="timeinms"` and do the same thing for `now`).